# pdfminer reads numbers incorrectly when the pdf text is in hebrew

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, pdfminer

I use this pdfminer code to read from pdf:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages,   password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text
```

The extracted text seems correct including numbers.

I tried to use the same code to read PDFs in Hebrew (by adding [::-1] to the results so that it appears from right to left). With regards to letters, the text appears correctly. However, when it comes to numbers, although the code extracts them, the wrong numbers show up.

Any ideas whys?

Comment: Are you sure adding `[::-1]` is the correct thing to do? Because if the PDF tool does a good job, the characters should be in reading order. Strings don't have a left or right edge, they only have start and end. Right-to-left or left-to-right is a matter of *displaying* the characters.

Comment: PDF gives me the correct chars, but he doesn't know that the lines in Hebrew are from right to left so I must do it myself.   Anyways that does not affect the numbers since even before reversing the strings I see the wrong numbers